# Cannot set split ActionBar using support libraries

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have searched a lot on the internet but I still can't set split action bar. I also attempted official documentation's methods but nothing works.

I'm building app with `minSdkVersion = 9` and `targetSdkVersion = 21` and using `AppCompat Theme` I successfully changed the color of actionbar and text but cannot add split ActionBar.

I added `uiOptions = "splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in `manifest` file and also added `meta-data` for backward support but split action bar is still not visible on either **narrow** or **wide** screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appcompat-v7` as of version `21` no longer supports the split action bar, as Android 5.0 no longer supports the split action bar.

If you want that sort of thing, you have to do it yourself, via a `Toolbar` or something that you position at the bottom of the screen.